# How to define a repository in Maven pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

How can we define a repository in the pom.xml?

For example if dependency is not found in the repository defined in settings.xml then search for the dependency in the repository defined in pom.xml.

An example on how this can be achieved would be great.

I am aware that placing repositories in the pom.xml is not a good option, but circumstances are pushing for this.

Comment: I do use a repository manager, although this repo does not contain all the jars, so i need to connect to the old repo.

Comment: Put that old repo into the repository manager and that's it.

Comment: Are any of these answers satisfactory? Perhaps you could mark one as correct now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) (example reproduced as is here):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
      <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
</project>
```